# Angular, redirect from one controller to onother

Tags: angularjs, node.js, redirect

I'm developing an application using angularjs starting from **https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed** project. I'm trying to redirect from a controller to another without success. I need to do this from controller because i have some controls to do before redirect. I'm using location object for do it..

Here is my code for redirect:

```
$scope.infostore = function() {
    $location.path( 'store' );
}
```

Here is my route configuration:

```
angular.module('myApp.routes', ['ngRoute'])    
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {    
      $routeProvider.when('/home', {
         authRequired: true,
         templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', 
         controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      });    
      $routeProvider.when('/apps', {
         authRequired: true,
         templateUrl: 'partials/apps.html',
         controller: 'appsController'
      });    
      $routeProvider.when('/store', {
         authRequired: true,
         templateUrl: 'partials/store.html',
         controller: 'storeController'
      });    
      $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});    
   }]);
```

But every time i call the method 'infostore' in appsController angular redirect me to 'home'

Why? I just try to use apply() without success on main scope.

Here is my store controller:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('storeController', function($location, $firebase, $modal, $scope, database, $http, $rootScope, $routeParams) {

    var ref = database.returnRef("users/"+$rootScope.auth.user.uid+"/apps");
    $scope.apps = $firebase(ref);


});
```

Here is store html:

```
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h3>
                <span>{{ 'myappslong' | translate }}</span>
            </h3>
        </div>

    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-1"></div>

        <div class="col-md-10">

            store

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the URL from the first controller: http://localhost:8000/app/index.html#/apps

Comment: `$location.path('/store')`

Comment: Just try it, but doesn't work..

Comment: i think the problem is after redirect, i can see store page for half second and then angular automatically redirect to home.

Comment: There is something happening that we cannot tell from the code that's provided, then.  See this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/jujuloyufo/1/edit?html,js,output) that I created -- your code works fine based on what you've given us.

Comment: Can you post your store controller + html for better debugging?

Comment: Toms jsBin works perfectly, try to understand whats different in your project.

Comment: Still hard to tell based on what you've shown.  What does `database.returnRef()` do?

Comment: It simply create a reference to firebase

Comment: I try to update to last angular and fb versione, but i have the same problem. I think the problem is about route.js

Answer (score 0):

Solved, there was an error in my html code. Using location.path works correctly.